# How to access to a variable outside of event function in android

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` and on row click I show `AlertDialog` with data about selected element.

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
 alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        // I need to access 'i' here somehow?

                    }});
```

My `AlertDialog` have action button and here I need data from selected element.
But inside event function for alert button I can't access data `i` and `l` from outside function.
Is there some way to access it or it should be passed somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// I need to access 'i' here somehow?
i should final

public void onItemClick(final AdapterView adapterView, View view, final int i, long l)
    adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i)